# Can a public and private non-overloaded constructors exist?

Tags: c#, struct, constructor

Any way to have a private constructor coexist with the public one with the same signature? I've included bare bones code.

```
struct Wouble
{
    private double value;

    public Wouble(double value)
    {
        this.value = ExpensiveValidation(value);
    }

    private Wouble(double value)
    {
        this.value = value;
    }

    public static implicit operator Wouble(double value)
    {
        return new Wouble(value);
    }

    public static Wouble operator +(Wouble a, Wouble b)
    {
        // Would like this to call the private constructor without ExpensiveValidation
        new Wouble(a.value + b.value);
    }
}
...
Wouble a = new Wouble(5.2);
Wouble b = new Wouble(8.1);
Wouble c = a + b;   // Calls overloaded operator +, I don't want to validate again
```

The only workaround I could think of is to add a dummy unused parameter to the private constructor to force an overload like this:

```
private Wouble(double value, int dontValidate)
{ this.value = value; }
```

and pass a extra ,0 into all internal calls. I also want it to be performant, no unnecessary helper methods etc.

Comment: no. imagine a `Static Wobble CreateInstance()` in your class which calles the constructor.  how should the compiler know which constructor to use? as an alternative: only implement a private constructor, and let `CreateInstance` do the validation.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can try using constructor *without parameters* (note, that `struct` always has it):

```
struct Wouble 
{
    private double value;

    public Wouble(double value)
    {
        this.value = ExpensiveValidation(value);
    }

    public static implicit operator Wouble(double value)
    {
        // ExpensiveValidation will be performed
        return new Wouble(value);
    }

    public static Wouble operator +(Wouble a, Wouble b)
    {
        // No validation here
        return new Wouble() 
        {
            value = a.value + b.value
        };
    }
}
```

Then

```
// Expensive validation will be performed
Wouble a = new Wouble(5.2);
// Expensive validation will be performed
Wouble b = new Wouble(8.1);
// No expenisive validation, 5.2 + 8.1 = 13.3 is assigned to value  
Wouble c = a + b;
```

Comment: Technically, I believe a struct *can't* have a parameterless constructor (but it always behaves as if it has one).  Though I could be mistaken.  It may vary on C# version and compiler implementation details also.

Comment: @MattJohnson-Pint: Default constructors for structs were added in C# 10 (but they've been possible at the IL level from the very beginning of .NET). You can circumvent them, though, with a `default` expression, and it's identical to how it works if a default constructor is not defined.

Comment: OK that does answer the question as asked and does help and I accepted the answer, but in my actual code I have a little more than just a.value + b.value that I can't fit into a member initializer without a method call which I was trying to avoid. So I might have to go with my workaround for performance.

Comment: Actually it might not make any difference, I will do some benchmarks. ty.

Answer (score 0):

While @Dmitry gave you an answer (a good one), it is worth noting that you are, perhaps, mixing concerns (performance) with overloading (about functionality/behavior), and this can lead to all kinds of issues.

The two concepts are orthogonal (unrelated) so trying to conflate them is counterproductive. I would suggest conveying intent through some other mechanism. Maybe introduce a factory class that does the validation, and leave "normal" initialization to the constructor.

Constructors, generally, should avoid excessive computation.

Going back to the original question, we know now that the short answer is "no, you cannot have the same constructor only vary by access modifier". Overloading is based on the signature of the method by parameter count and type. Return type (if it was a method and not a constructor, and access modifiers are not part of overload resolution).